# Hamcrest Date Matchers

Tags: java, date, hamcrest

I need to test before/after on dates in a certain test case. I'd like to use [Hamcrest matchers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamcrest) if possible.

Are there any matchers for Hamcrest (Java) for working with Dates?  If so, what package/class would I find the particular date matcher functions in?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The [OrderingComparison::greaterThan](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/number/OrderingComparison.java#L34) matcher will work on any type which is comparable to itself (it's in the `org.hamcrest.number` package, but it's not actually number-specific). Date is such a type.

Comment: Thanks. It seems they've got rid of the class in favour of a static factory method, which makes a really stable link impossible, but i've fixed it as far as i can.

Comment: That's true. There are also extensions that provide some more easy-to-read   methods. E.g., [Cirneco](https://github.com/ozimov/cirneco) provides the matcher `J7Matchers::after` that is an alias for `OrderingComparison::greaterThan`. From my point of view, _sematic_ is always important in unit test, that's why I usually prefer the fulent approach provided by Google Truth, but I sometimes have to handle with Hamcrest in legacy projects.

Answer (score 19):

There is a library of hamcrest date matchers provided by the library at https://github.com/eXparity/hamcrest-date which is also available for maven, ivy, etc at

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.exparity</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-date</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It supports various matchers for dates so allows constructs such as

```
Date myBirthday = new Date();
MatcherAssert.assertThat(myBirthday, DateMatchers.after(Moments.today()));
```

or

```
Date myBirthday = new Date();
MatcherAssert.assertThat(myBirthday, DateMatchers.isToday());
```

Answer (score 7):

You can have a look at the new Date Matchers that will be added to hamcrest (I don't know when thought):

[Date matchers discussion/code changes on github](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/pull/6)

After a quick look it seems there will be a new package ***org.hamcrest.date*** containing:

- IsAfter
- IsBefore
- IsSameDayOfTheMonth
- IsSameDayOfTheWeek
- IsSameDayOfTheYear
- IsSameHour
- IsSameInstant
- IsSameMinute
- IsSameMonth
- IsSameSecond
- IsSameYear
- IsWithin

Answer (score 4):

There are certain hamcrest extensions that can ease some of the testing related to dates. Please [check here.](https://github.com/wcmatthysen/hamcrest-text-patterns)

Answer (score 0):

The [`Matchers#greaterThan`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) matcher works with `Date`s and other `Comparable` objects.

Here's the way to check that your date is greater than or equal (≥) to some expected date:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.greaterThan;
import static org.hamcrest.core.AnyOf.anyOf;
...

Date expectedMin = new Date()
// Execute the method being tested
Date resultDate = getDate();
// Validate
assertThat(resultDate, anyOf(greaterThan(expectedMin), equalTo(expectedMin)))
```

Answer (score -1):

There is also the [Cirneco extension](https://github.com/ozimov/cirneco). It has several `Date` specific matchers (e.g. `monday()`) and others that apply to dates because of the implementation of `Comparable` (see for instance `between()`, `betweenInclusive()`). The plan is to support also Joda Time in the JDK7 version of the library and the new date-based classes in the JDK8 version (mainly `LocalDate`).

You can do assertions like:

```
final Date date = new Date();
assertThat(date, is(monday())); // JUnit style
given(date).assertIs(monday()); // Cirneco style
```

You can use the following dependency for a JDK7-compliant project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
  <artifactId>java7-hamcrest-matchers</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or the following if you are using JDK8

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
  <artifactId>java8-hamcrest-matchers</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison

org.assertj:assertj-core:3.12.2

```
assertThat(actual)
    .usingRecursiveComparison()
    .ignoringFieldsMatchingRegexes("fieldToIgore")
    .isEqualTo(expected);
```

Comment: How is this related to the topic?